# Integrating React / Preact based widget library into a legacy web app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, bundle, preact

A client has request me to build a set of reusable components / widget to be integrated on legacy web development (JQuery, ES5 based).

My idea is to create:

- A library that will make use of React / Preact to build the widgets.
- Use ES6/TS + webpack + babel, to end up transpiling to ES5 and packing it into a library.

My main concern comes with the third party libraries dependencies(e.g. react, react-dom or preact…), I’m thinking about taking one of this two approaches:

A. **Treat third party libraries as just external dependencies**, the legacy application that needs to consume my widget library have to reference that library.

- Pros: no extra weight added to my bundle, this library could be used in legacy apps and modern apps.
- Cons: possible versioning hell in the future, e.g. we release the library for React 16, and in the future,  they mix other widgets from another library that depend on React 18 (maybe a possible workaround is to fix versions and perform an all or nothing migration from time to time).

B. **Embed preact into the library bundle:**

- Pros: only adding 3 to 4 Kb to the library bundle, the bundle is self contained.
- Cons: probably we could not use these components on modern development (e.g. compose it with other components from other react based libraries).

What could be the best approach? Is there another option available? Does approach B make sense? (haven’t tried that one before).

Comment: Have you complated?

Comment: We went for option B, by following that approach we added some extra cost, but no dependencies hell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would lean to the **B** answer.

- if you need to combine them with other libraries, you still have the sources in ES6+ which allows you to import them easily inside a new project.
- I actually only work with the B approach because it removes the dependency nightmare. You know that you ship code with the compatible react version, and you have total control of the final ES5 code with babel.
- If you worry that much over 10kb, there's plenty of ways to reduce size (enabling compression, making sure you use production bundle, etc).

Comment: Thanks @Chris R what libraries are you using in your components library? React or Preact?

Comment: Marked as answer, thanks Chris, just read about angular 7 approach (ivy) to deliver lite web components  and it's quite similar to what you propose (lite weight minimum bootstrap + components) Thanks a lot for your guidance

Comment: Could you provide the link of the article you just read? For future reader asking the same questions. =)

Comment: It was on a public talk (not recorded) about Ivy and getting a pretty small bundle size on angular6, found this link: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/first-look-angular-ivy the recommendation from the speaker, was... develop your web components using angular 6 + ivy tree shaking, and you will get a very small angular foot print (10 Kb's approach)